# Conditional python regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse the nmap output for service discovery with the following regex.

```
regex = "(?P<ports>[\d]+)\/(?P<protocol>tcp|udp)\s+(?P<state>open|filtered|closed)\s+(?P<service>[\w\S]*)\s+(?P<reason>\S*\s+\S+\s+\S*(?=\w)\w)(?:\n|(?P<version>.*))"
```

It could parse the output with the following pattern.

```
PORT    STATE    SERVICE    REASON         VERSION
80/tcp   open     http     str1 str2 str3    version string here
```

But is not able to correctly parse the following output.

```
PORT    STATE    SERVICE    REASON         VERSION
161/tcp filtered snmp       no-response
```

Is there any single regex which can parse both the above patterns?

Comment: Have you thought about using Python mappings to nmap? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-nmap

Comment: I don't think you can solve this with regex, because there's no way to describe a pattern which determines where one column ends and another begins.

Comment: Well, you may also study optional groups, i.e. `(?:....)?`, and see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/nqTADT/1).

Comment: @Jerome... I have tried the nmap python module which is really amazing. But the purpose of parsing using the way I am doing is to parse existing nmap output files. The nmap python module will require the complete development from scratch which will need the invocation of nmap scripts using nmap module.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew ... Thanks for the response. I did try the solution you provided. No luck. The port on the next line after the "no-response" is getting a part of the version. Will need some other workaround to handle the format which has <CR><LF> after the "Reason" value string.

Comment: Yeah, suit yourself. Only you can answer your question since we do not  have all the data, and you have not shared the exact specs.

Comment: hi Wiktor. Here is the data set 1. Nmap scan report for <IP Address 1>
Host is up, received user-set (0.27s latency).
Scanned at <Time> <Time zone>for 60s
PORT    STATE    SERVICE    REASON         VERSION
161/tcp open     service1 reason one 54
179/tcp filtered service2        no-response
646/tcp open     service3   reason one 54
The port 179 record here has reason as "no-reason' followed by <CR><LF>. The version information is not present. The format specified in the regex has \S*\s+\S+\s+\S*(?=\w)\w which matched with most of the reason format but not with record for port 179.

Comment: The regex I am using matches with the rest of the nmap out put format which is as follows.                                                         PORT      STATE  SERVICE          REASON         VERSION
22/tcp    closed service1         reason one 52
1883/tcp  closed service3         reason two 52
8883/tcp  open   service4         reason four 52

Answer (score 0):

You can add an alternative for hardcoded `no-response`, would it help?

```
(?P<ports>[\d]+)\/(?P<protocol>tcp|udp)\s+(?P<state>open|filtered|closed)\s+(?P<service>[\w\S]*)\s+(?P<reason>(:?\S*\s+\S+\s+\S*(?=\w)\w)|(:?no-response))(?:\n|(?P<version>.*))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yk2rbG/1/)

Comment: Thanks for quick response @mrzasa. But the suggestion did not work for me. The pattern difference is as follows. There may be "Reason" value string in the form of "<\S+\s+\S+\s+\S\s+]>" followed by version string. The other pattern of reason string being "[a-zA-Z0-9]" followed by new line character. The first regex mentioned does not match when it encounters \n and takes the next line i.e. port protocol string as version string. Here is the sample output for reference.

Comment: PORT    STATE    SERVICE    REASON         VERSION
161/tcp filtered snmp       no-response
179/tcp open     tcpwrapped syn-ack ttl 54